# How to control memory with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

My final working program is simply like:

```
for i in range(start_number, end_number):
    page = urlopen(http://targetpage/i.html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    link = soup.select('div#link')
    tag = soup.select('div#tag')

    for l, t in zip(link, tag):
        for link_reference in l.find_all('a'):
            tag_reference in t.get_text()
            final_zip = zip(link_reference, tag_reference)
    print(final_zip)
print("end")
```

it looks very simple structure, but the thing is,

it feed too many memory.
I don't know how to check exactly "only python code use memory",

but when I open this code from cmd, and look in taskmanager,

manager's python.exe process get the memory start with 10,000k to end with 23,000k.

why it use so much amount of memory, and how to decrease it?

Comment: 23 MB doesn't seem like a big deal for today's computers. Do you have a specific memory usage requirement?

Comment: If your code works, try asking this on Code Review.

Comment: @GregHewgill of course it is not a big deal, but I just want to know why usage increase over double. and if I run this on arm, it will be a problem

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 uhm... i really don't know, what is code review?

Comment: It's [a SE site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask for advice on how to clean up and improve working code.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of cycles of the **for** statement is large, you could use **xrange** instead of range, **itertools.izip** instead of zip for efficient looping.

Comment: i learned itertools.izip and xrange are deleted in py3, instead of zip and range.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use xrange instand of range
2. use gc.collect() to speed up memory return

Comment: Question is tagged Python3 in which range works like xrange in Python2.